# Cannot suggest migration to Graphic Design

Tags: support, migration

Graphic Design SE just came out of Beta, we are all chuffed over there.

However; I cannot seem to suggest migration from StackOverflow to GraphicDesign via the flag options. Here is what happens when I flag a question for migration. GD simply is not an option:

[image]

I *can* do it manually, by using the "other" option and write it, but surely that means more work for the mods here than necessary.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. I understand it is 5 sites by design, I just wonder if it's worth maybe adding GD as a migration option to give the site more visibility, temporarily. Or making it easier to find (newer) sites (whose names are not that popular yet!).

Comment: BTW Stack Overflow has a space, as does Graphic Design.

Comment: @Yisela I can't speak to them adding it but in my limited experience as a mod on SO, more times than not the request to migrate to another site is just wrong or the question is not in good enough shape to pitch it from SO to another site.  Basically, we don't want to migrate crap even if it is on-topic for another site.

Comment: @bluefeet fair enough, I wasn't sure how many people actually used this option. Do you think there's a need for a clearer, better way to migrate stuff as the network gets bigger?

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson sorry, what space are you referring to?

Comment: @Random I'm saying it's `Stack Overflow`, not `StackOverflow`. Look at the title of the page on SO home.

Comment: @Yisela Unfortunately the migration from SO to any site it really difficult because there are so many sites now it is really hard to know what is or is not on-topic for each one.  At least for me, if I run across one that has been flagged and I'm not sure if it is a good fit, I'll ping a mod on the targeted site before sending it.

Comment: @bluefeet i suppose this is the way it is, good to know there is a reason and not a hiccough. Though from my perspective, I sometimes swipe through SO for unanswered Qs that fit our site. Now at least, I know exactly that pinging is the way to go.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson if my spelling offends you so much, you are welcome to edit the post. As you can do with any post.

Comment: @RandomO'Reilly yeah unfortunately at this point just flag as other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the intended behavior.  There are only 5 sites that are available for migration from Stack Overflow and Graphic Design is not one of them.

If you feel that another site is the correct place, then use Other to flag for moderators.

Comment: I still don't understand why there isn't an "other sites" button where you can search like in the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™.

Comment: @totymedli IMHO it's better that way: there are only a few times that this appears. Most uses say "ohh that site scope looks good, let's give it to them" without verifying it's a good question for them. Mods have tools to communicate and can send a quick message to ask if that would be a good question. As bluefeet pointed out in the comments of the question, usually questions asked on the wrong site aren't high quality.